# How to update/migrate from Vite 2 to Vite 3 (leveraging Vue) with NPM

Tags: vue.js, npm, vite

This sounds like a simple question, but for some reason I wasn't able to find the actual process/commands for updating Vite 2 to Vite 3 with npm. I read through the [announcement](https://vitejs.dev/blog/announcing-vite3.html) and the [migration guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html) (and more), which is all helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

Realized it's probably not written out because it's 'too intuitive.' First, be sure to read the [migration guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html) and adjust breaking changes accordingly. Then use the following two commands.

One to update Vite itself:

```
npm install vite@latest
```

And the second to update the Vite Vue plugin:

```
npm install @vitejs/plugin-vue@latest
```

Hope this saves someone the headache of searching!